# Receipt template formatting (still) broken?

Tags: civimember, 4.7, message-templates, receipts

We've upgraded civicrm multiple times the last few years. At a certain point, the receipt templates broke. It stopped showing credit card information and membership start/end date (for membership receipts) became blank.

I've just reverted 'back' to the default templates, assuming that default is the same as the most recent version of civicrm (so, not the 4.5 default we started with, but the 4.7 default we are at right now). But these fields are still broken.

So perhaps these are not the most recent templates. Are there more recent templates I can download somewhere ?

Particularly, I see

```
<td {$valueStyle}>
{$mem_start_date}
</td>
```

Shouldn't that be

```
<td {$valueStyle}>
{$mem_start_date|crmDate}
</td>
```

Or even

```
<td {$valueStyle}>
{$mem_start_date|truncate:10:''|crmDate}
</td>
```

and

```
 {$credit_card_type}<br />
 {$credit_card_number}
```

prints nothing but blanks, as does

```
 {$credit_card_exp_date|truncate:7:''|crmDate}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the current template files in the repository (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core).  It's not clear whether you're on 5.x or in fact still on 4.7 but previous versions should be available as well for you to pull from.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what to look for though - are they defined as files in a sort of tpl format .. can i search by extension ?

Comment: If you go here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/find/master and type receipt, the file finder should help you pull up the relevant files.